# Avast hangs Outlook beacuse of STARTTLS

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, ssl, avast, tls

I have a problem getting mail from my university's IMAP server. I have found that if you try to use STARTTLS in your client, connection hangs forever. I reported the problem, but they didn't solve it.

Now, my **real** problem is that even if I disable Outlook 2010's security, Avast antivirus, acting as a man-in-the-middle with Outlook, activates the STARTTLS option, causing Outlook to hang.

If I temproarily disable Avast, I can download the email without using the secure protocols, but I don't like turning my antivirus on and off every time.

## My question is

How to prevent Avast from using the STARTTLS protocol with IMAP? Please notice that I **can't** use POP3 as I share mail across computers.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work if you uncheck SSL for inbound and outbound mail.

Tools -> Accounts -> Mail -> Properties -> Advanced -> ***uncheck*** SSL

Also, [this article](https://support.avast.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=458) might help you find other places SSL/TLS gets enabled in Avast.

Comment: Some systems won't work with SSL unchecked.

Comment: Thanks for that AndrejaKo. I've added an article from Avast Support Center that shows where else you can enable or disable SSL/TLS. Hopefully, djechelon can play around with those settings if my intial solution does not work correctly.